# Bokeh plot not updating

Tags: python, bokeh

I would love some help, I'm going in circles here. I know I'm doing something stupid but my plot isn't updating. I can't debug to see if my filter function isn't working or there's a problem that my inputs for the plot aren't linked the dynamic source input. Since even the starting plot doesn't take the initialized parameters I think it's something there. PS- any advice on having a select all, including all in the categorical choices for the select boxes would be amazing too.

Cheers,
Tom

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, push_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Panel, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import (CheckboxGroup, Slider, Select, TextInput, RangeSlider, Tabs, CheckboxButtonGroup, TableColumn, DataTable, Select)

from bokeh.layouts import layout, column, row, Widgetbox
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.palettes import Category20_16

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application

weather = pd.read_csv('YYYYYY.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True, index_col=[1], encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

def style(p):
    # Title 
    p.title.align = 'center'
    p.title.text_font_size = '20pt'
    p.title.text_font = 'serif'

    # Axis titles
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'

    # Tick labels
    p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
    p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '12pt'

    return p    

def make_plot(src):
    p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="'2018'", toolbar_location="below", tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
    p.circle(x="Deal_Number", y="USD_Base", source=src, size=7, line_color=None)
    p = style(p)
    return p

TOOLTIPS=[
    ("Name", "@Target"),
    ("$", "@Round"),
    ("Country", "@CC")
]

def get_dataset(deal_num, ccstring, descstring, vertstring):
    df_filter = weather[weather['USD_Base'] >=(deal_num) & weather['CC'].str.contains(ccstring) & weather['Description'].str.contains(descstring) & weather['Vertical Market'].str.contains(vertstring)]
    return ColumnDataSource(df_filter)


def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    deal_num = int(deal_select.value)
    ccstring = str(cc_select.value)
    descstring = str(description_select.value)
    vertstring = str(vert_select.value)
    new_src = get_dataset(deal_num, ccstring, descstring, vertstring)
    src.data.update(new_src.data)

# Create Input controls
deal_select = Slider(title="$ Invested", value=0, start=0, end=200, step=2)
cclist = weather["CC"].unique().tolist()
cc_select = Select(title="Country Name:", options= cclist, value='GB')
description_select = TextInput(title="Company description contains")
vertlist = weather["Vertical Market"].unique().tolist()
vert_select = Select(title="Vertical:", options= ['All'] + vertlist, value='None')


controls = widgetbox(deal_select, cc_select, description_select, vert_select)

deal_select.on_change('value', update_plot) 
cc_select.on_change('value',update_plot)
description_select.on_change('value',update_plot)
vert_select.on_change('value',update_plot)

# Make the deal data source

src = get_dataset(deal_num = deal_select.value, 
            ccstring = cc_select.value, 
            descstring = description_select.value, 
            vertstring = vert_select.value)

# Make the deal plot
p = make_plot(src)

layout = row(controls, p)

# Make a tab with the layout 
tab = Panel(child=layout, title = '2018')

# Put all the tabs into one application
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab])

# Put the tabs in the current document for display
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating a glyph, you need to change the datasource for that glyph directly. In your case, you should assign the circle glyph to a variable, such as:

`circle = p.circle(x="Deal_Number", y="USD_Base", source=src, size=7, line_color=None)`

Then in your `update_plot(attr, old, new)` function try this:

`circle = p.select_one({'name':'circle'})`

`circle.data_source.data = new_src.data`

For selecting all, possibly the [MultiSelect Widget](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#multiselect) would work?

Comment: PJW thanks for the reply. Yeah, I thought since I was changing the source in the update function & the plot function refs source as source that this would update it. I modelled the code of this update function (https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-bokeh-in-python-part-ii-interactions-a4cf994e2512) which seems to account for all three controls. Added your code and got this error moving the slider ('attr': 'value', 'new': 110}], 'references': []}: ValueError("expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got ColumnDataSource(id='1294'). Doesn't seem to know where to put the update value

Comment: What is the specific line of code that `ValueError` is referencing? I would confirm that the update function is receiving the `new` value (print or log statement in the update function), then use `new` in the function (i.e. `deal_num = int(new)`).

Comment: You may also want to simplify things by making a single update function for just the `deal_select` slider (using `new` as in previous comment). Then you can better isolate and see how things work. In this function, `ccstring`, `descstring`, `vertstring` will remained unchanged. I usually use the `new` value in the update function, rather than grabbing the widget's `.value` from within the update function.

Comment: PJW thank you for continuing to help. Ok, I've taken out the other inputs and just have the slider. The new value is going to the update function, proof of this is it is printing out the value, 38 in the test case pasted. Here is the code (https://pastebin.com/1g66UXMY) We are still stuck with the error it doesn't know what to do with the value, expects a dict or dataframe but gets a columndatasource so I'm guessing the ColumnDataSource(df_filter) or it could be the next line new_src = ColumnDataSource(new_src)

Comment: Your pastebin shows the error message, but what line of code is the error referencing? (i.e. where is it failing?)

Comment: In my cmd for the Bokeh server that is the output, there is no break of code I only get that error message when I move the slider? Am I missing something?

Comment: hmmm... `get_dataset()` returns a ColumnDataSource, so why are you creating again with `new_src = ColumnDataSource(new_src)`?

Comment: Now have try work out how to take the other inputs and by able to update together

Comment: Cool, sounds like you're on the right track. And are you redefining `deal_num` with `new` or  `deal_select.value`? You should post the correct answer when you figure it out. Or I can modify mine if it is close...

Comment: Will do, with new at the moment but will try DSV and I will update the post once it's figured out and mark yours as correct. Thanks again.